# Green Exceptions?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, exception

When unhandled exceptions are encountered in VStudio usually the debugger highlights the line *YELLOW* as the line that threw the exception.

However sometimes I encounter exceptions where the debugger highlights them green as shown:

[image]

I've always treated them as normal exceptions, but today I decided to ask since google/bing produced no results for "Visual Studio Green Exceptions"

Comment: +1 for the funny title.

Comment: These are the ONLY exceptions you will ever throw, if you *care about the environment at all*.

Comment: I first thought the question was about throwing exceptions in an environment-aware way to minimize energy consumption and CO output... didn't live to expectations.

Comment: Lol thanks guys, truth be told it didn't cross my mind when writing it. Sorry I didn't live up to your expectations Developer Art

Comment: @Developer Art: Feel free to ask such a question.  :)

Comment: !!! I didn't know you could link in pictures on stack-overflow! I wish i could +1 adrianbanks for showing me that :o

Comment: See, this type of subtlety completely escapes color-blind developers like myself. Thanks for bringing to my attention that the world is more complex than a binary "no exception, good / exception, bad".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The line is highlighted yellow if that is the line that directly threw the exception (typically a `throw` statement).
It's green if the line is a call to a different function that threw the exception (typically a call to a .Net function that threw an exception).

Comment: In other words: play a bit with navigating the call stack. You will see yellow if you are on the topmost stack frame, and green for every frame below that.

Comment: @SLaks can you give a reference for this. the answer is not clear enough.

Answer (score 6):

The yellow line is the line where the exception is really thrown.

The green line indicates a line that is indirectly affected.

I think the screenshot makes it clear. Note that I had to use the "Callstack" window and switch to the `Main()` method in order to achieve this effect.

[image: Green and yellow exception in Visual Studio]