# What is difference between Green Exceptions and Yellow Exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-debugging

I saw this question
[Green Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814769/green-exceptions/2814781?noredirect=1#comment52462089_2814781) before asking this question.
the answer is really not descriptive at all, and it is very short, and I did got the idea.
you can refer this question but really it was NOT helpful for me at all.
and I want a more explanation.

Can some one please explain to me (In Details) what the difference when the visual studio show the exception with Green background, from the exceptions which shown with the Yellow background ???

Comment: @SamAxe please did you read the question ??? i said that this question is not fit me and i did not the understand the answer of it

Comment: You can petition to reopen the question if you think it was closed in error.  However, the linked question is *quite* clear.  If you are unable to understand it, you will most likely be unable to understand any other answer.  If there is some *specific* detail you don't understand, try asking about that detail.

Comment: @Sam I think OP will understand it with simple examples. Also OP already note that the link couldnt help.

Comment: @SamAxe please un mark this question as duplicated, may be some body could help me, you are prevent any body from helping me by doing this.

Comment: @SamAxe also this topic has very little number of question, i did not found any other question about this topic in the stackoverflow, and as i told you the answer is very short, by making this question, maybe we will receive better answer which may be helpful for me and for others. think about this from the point of view that this will rich the Stackoverflow and make it has more answers and info, which will help others

Comment: @HakamFostok I believe you are [adding to the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303075/11683). The answer in the duplicate question is very clear and thus does not require a longer explanation (hence there are none).

Comment: I have added another answer with a screenshot. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32295100/480982

Comment: @ThomasWeller thank you very much