# Why doesn't Debug.Assert work with 64-bit? (No Symbols Loaded)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

I have reproduced this problem on two separate 64-bit machines (both running VS2012). Here's how: Create a new console application with nothing in it but this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{   class Program
    {   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, open Project settings, navigate to **Build-> General -> Platform target:**, and select x64 (or, alternatively, select "Any CPU", and disable the "Prefer 32-bit" setting), and run the program.

The `Assertion Failed` dialog appears, but hitting "Retry" doesn't break into the code, instead it just opens a "No Symbols Loaded" window, which says "Symbol loading skipped" (see screenshot below).
[image: Symbol loading for optimized module System.dll was skipped because Just My Code is enabled]

If I change the **Platform target** to x86 (or *re-enable* the "Prefer 32-bit" setting), the Asserts start working properly again.

*Notes:*

1. My .pdb file seems fine; breakpoints work perfectly with either setting.
2. If I select **Disable Just My Code**, it still doesn't work; it just takes me to a window that says "Source Not Available."

So my question is, *how do I get Debug Assertions to break into the code in a 64-bit application?* (or why does disabling the "Prefer 32-bit" setting break it?)

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32295100/4136325

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why this is happening, but, I tried this out and *is* breaking into the code, it's just breaking at a line deeper in the call stack:

[image: Stack trace upon Debug.Assert fail on 64-bit app]

If you bring up the Call Stack window you can navigate to the frame where your Debug.Assert failed.