# VS 2015 debugging pause color

Tags: visual-studio

I'm debugging the project and hit 'pause'. Sometimes the line is marked green (most often) and sometimes yellow, what's the difference? (Visual Studio 2015)

(Debugging C# console application, net 4.5)

Comment: Debugging what? Please remember that Visual Studio has support for many languages. Be more specific. You should know this, given your high reputation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Green Exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814769/green-exceptions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Green line indicates that the code on the highlighted statement is executing. The code may, for example, be waiting for an event or has called some code that has no source available. A yellow highlight means the statement is the next to be executed when you step forward.

You can easily see this by going back in the call stack when debugging. The selected step in the stack is shown green. Other steps are shown in gray background, at least with my default settings.