# Green highlight of code while debugging in web-api

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using a web-api projects for some parts of projects to get data from that api and I need to debug and trace my code as usual but some parts of this api code are going to debug mode without setting any debugger at that line and that line is being highlighted with green color.It does not influence on any code or result but it is really disgusting during work and I am curious to know the reason

Comment: Maybe you can get some help from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177583/vs-2015-debugging-pause-color). How does the scenario looks like? If you create a new web-api project the same issue persists?

Comment: You can try Tools=>Import and export settings=>reset all settings and Tools=>options=>environment=>general to change the color theme to check if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your great answers it was absolutely useful

Comment: I've just added it as an answer, if my answer is helpful, could you please help mark it. Many thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Green highlight of code

Maybe you can get some help from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177583/vs-2015-debugging-pause-color).

Also, you can try Tools=>Import and export settings=>reset all settings and Tools=>options=>environment=>general to change the color theme to check if it helps.